# Algorithm to transform tree data in Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, tree

How can i change my tree made of Array of hashes into another structure such as:

My data looks like :

```
{
  "A": [
         { "A1": [] },
         { "A2": [] },
         {
           "A3": [
                   {
                     "A31": [
                              { "A311": [] },
                              { "A312": [] }
                            ]
                   }
                 ]
         }
       ]
}
```

into something like :

```
{
  "name":     "A",
  "children": [
                { "name": "A1" },
                { "name": "A2" },
                {
                  "name":     "A3",
                  "children": [
                                {
                                  "name":     "A31",
                                  "children": [
                                                { "name": "A311" },
                                                { "name": "A312" }
                                              ]
                                }
                              ]
                }
              ]
}
```

I tried a few things but nothing worked as I hoped.

This is how i move into my tree

```
def recursive(data)
    return if data.is_a?(String)
    data.each do |d|
        keys = d.keys
        keys.each do |k|
            recursive(d[k])
        end
    end
   return data
end
```

I tried my best to follow [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so to clarify :

- The tree can have a unlimited deeph
- Names are more complexe than A1, A2 ...

Comment: I don't know about you, but that manner of displaying adjacent hashes (`}, {`) really disrupts my ability to read the code :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I tried to make the json more readable for users ... my bad if it does the opposite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
λ = ->(h) { [h[:name], h[:children] ? h[:children].map(&λ).to_h : []] }

[λ.(inp)].to_h
#⇒ {
#  "A" => {
#    "A1" => [],
#    "A2" => [],
#    "A3" => {
#      "A31" => {
#        "A311" => [],
#        "A312" => []
#      }
#    }
#  }
# }
```

This solution returns hashes that are not wrapped in arrays inside. If you really want to wrap nested hashes with arrays, map them in `λ`.

Comment: Very nice, mudsie! `λ` has shown up in your answers with increasing regularity.

Comment: More questions that could be solved with `proc`s ⇒ more `λ`s.

Comment: I need to change my data on the other side... but thanks for this tips !

Comment: The plot thickens :) I wonder whether I got downvoted by a personal hater, by a λ-hater, or by a correct-solution-hater?

Comment: I upvoted the question for the sake of entropy constancy.

Comment: The downvoter was probably someone you [called on the carpet](https://www.vocabulary.com/articles/dictionary/called-on-the-carpet/).

Comment: @mudasobwa: how do you type the lambda symbol, btw? :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev ✓ I have a heavily customized keyboard layout. For `λ` itself one might just turn on greek layout, I guess. But it won’t work for ∀ symbol, like arrows ⇒⇐⇓⇑, long m-dashes—like this and flags ⚐⚑ :)

Comment: @mudasobwa: you have an [optimus keyboardus](http://www.artlebedev.com/everything/optimus/popularis/), don't you? :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Optimus is a bullshit. I tune up `xkb` symbols files.

Comment: Oh come on, it's not that bad. If it was a bit cheaper, I'd get one. :)

Comment: @mudasobwa Any lead on this in reverse ?! This algo making me crazy .. i'm stuck ...

Comment: What exactly you want to be explained? This is a `lambda`, that recursively calls itself when it meets non-empty children and just returns an empty array for empty children. The simplest recursion case, I am unsure what here might be explained in details.

Answer (score -1):

When you don't know how to implement something, always think the simplest case first.

#### Step 1: Convert `{"A1" => []}` to`{"name" => "A1", "children" => []}`

This is simple

```
def convert(hash)
  pair = hash.each_pair.first
  ["name", "children"].zip(pair).to_h
end
```

#### Step2: Recursively convert all hashes in `children`

```
def convert(hash)
  pair = hash.each_pair.first
  pair[1] = pair[1].map{|child| convert(child)}
  ["name", "children"].zip(pair).to_h
end
```

#### Step 3: Handle corner cases

If children is empty then omit it.

```
def convert(hash)
  pair = hash.each_pair.first
  pair[1] = pair[1].map{|child| convert(child)}
  result = {"name" => pair[0]}
  result.merge!("children" => pair[1]) if pair[1].any?
  result
end
```

Comment: Is this code supposed to raise `NoMethodError: undefined method 'map' for nil:NilClass`? _Edit:_ now it returns `{nil => []}`.

Comment: It still fails, btw.